# Is the hotspot JVM Bytecode Interpreter a tracing JIT?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

The question pretty much says it all, I've been looking around for an answer even through the VM spec but I it doesn't explicitly state it.

Comment: I assume hotpost means HotSpot.

Comment: @jtzero: even more interesting would be something showing if a "tracing JIT", which can optimize down to a single loop (instead of an entire method, like "regular" JIT do), offer any significant benefit over a non-tracing-JIT ;)      Say, if a regular JIT offers a "times 50" speedup and a tracing-JIT offers a "times 51" speedup, count me as really not impressed at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There are some other JVMs with tracing JITs, though: [HotPath](http://HotPath.GoogleCode.Com/) and [Maxine](http://Labs.Oracle.Com/projects/maxine/), for example.

Answer (score 3):

Aside: for those who don't know what a tracing JIT is, the following description comes from [this page](http://rayli.net/blog/2010/04/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-tracing-jit/):

> Although tracing JITs are a complex technology, the core concept is about optimizing execution of the hot paths in a program.  The emphasis is specifically on hot paths that return to the start of a path which sounds very much like a loop.  However, the traditional definition of a programming loop is only a subset of these hot paths.  The broader definition includes code that spans methods and possibly even modules.  This broader definition of a loop is what’s called a trace.

Answer (score 2):

Had to google what a "tracing JIT" was, but apparently it isn't.

[> non-tracing JIT implementations (Sun’s Java VM](http://rayli.net/blog/2010/04/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-tracing-jit/)

But it does optimise what you might call "hot spots".

How bytecode is optimised will not be part of the specification for the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not even a JIT actually, let alone a 'tracing JIT', whatever that might be.

Comment: You are nit picking.  Sure, the Hotspot bytecode *interpreter* is not a JIT *compiler* ... but it should be obvious from the context that the OP did not mean that!